# Refreshing Json feed inside javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm creating a page where it parses data from a json feed, but I wan't it to update every 30 seconds only refreshing the Div & the Jquery not actually refreshing the page.

I've tried a few things I've found on here but none have worked for me, The only thing that was happening is it was making page page go to infinite loop

Code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var username = "mrsyndicate";

$(window).load(function(){
$.getJSON("http://imraising.com/"+ username +"/json/livedata.json", function (data) {
    $.each(data.donation, function (index, item) {
        $("<div>").html('<font color="950202"><b>'+ item.screen + '</b></font>&nbsp;&nbsp;$' + item.amount).appendTo("#content");
        $("<div>").html(item.comment + '<br /><br />').appendTo("#content");
    });
});
});
</script>
```

And it loads on the page with

```
<div id="content"></div>
```

I've got it working all printing out the way I wan't it, only I Cannot get refresh working,
Any advice is welcomed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn it into a function that you can call:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    function getFeed() {            
        var username = "mrsyndicate";
        $.getJSON("http://imraising.com/"+ username +"/json/livedata.json", function (data) {
            $("#content").html("");
            $.each(data.donation, function (index, item) {
                $("<div>").html('<font color="950202"><b>'+ item.screen + '</b></font>&nbsp;&nbsp;$' + item.amount).appendTo("#content");
                $("<div>").html(item.comment + '<br /><br />').appendTo("#content");
            });
        });
    }
    getFeed();
    setInterval(getFeed, 30000);
});
```

Comment: won't that build-up repeated items? it probably needs a $("#content").html("") at the top...

Comment: You are correct. Thanks for the heads up. I fixed it.

Comment: I was coming back after testing it to say that exactly what dandavis said! Thanks! updated the code on my end testing it now!

Answer (score 0):

See [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval), it acts like a loop but you can change the interval so it doesn't crash even if it's infinite